# How can I pass the MyPojo object as reference to the map method?

Tags: java, reflection, methods, mapping

I have a WsField named an annotation.

WsField.java

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface WsField 
{
    String fieldName();
}
```

I use this WsField annotation in MyPojo class.

MyPojo.java

```
public class MyPojo
{
    @WsField(fieldName="Column1")
    private String fullName;


    public String getFullName()
    {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName)
    {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
}
```

I want to set the value of the fields that have WsField annotations in the map method.

WsMapper.java

```
public class WsMapper
{
    public static void map(Object instance,String attributeName, Object value) 
    {
        Class clsMeta = instance.getClass();
        for (Field field : clsMeta.getFields()) 
        {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(WsField.class)) 
            {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                String fieldName = field.getAnnotation(WsField.class).fieldName();
                if (fieldName.contains(attributeName)) 
                {
                   try 
                   {
                     field.set(instance, value);
                   } catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
                   {
                     e.printStackTrace();

                   } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
                   {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Application.java

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    
        MyPojo obj = new MyPojo();
        WsMapper.map(obj,"Column1", "Test");
        String fullName = obj.getFullName();
        System.out.println(fullName);
    }
}
```

How can I pass the MyPojo object as reference to the map method  ?

It works in the codes below.

```
MyPojo obj2 = new MyPojo();
Class  clsMeta = obj2.getClass();
String fieldName = ""; 
for (Field f : clsMeta.getDeclaredFields())
{
  if (f.isAnnotationPresent(WsField.class))
  {
      f.setAccessible(true);
      fieldName = f.getAnnotation(WsField.class).fieldName();
      if (fieldName.contains("Column1"))
      {
          try 
          {
            f.set(obj, "Test");
          } catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }   
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how in one case you have

```
for (Field field : clsMeta.getFields())
```

and in the other you have

```
for (Field f : clsMeta.getDeclaredFields())
```

Your `fullName` field is `private`. [`Class#getFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields--) does not return `private` fields. From the javadoc

> Returns an array containing `Field` objects **reflecting all the
>   accessible public fields** of the class or interface represented by this
>   Class object.

You'll have to use `Class#getDeclaredFields()` in your `map` method.